# Загрузка изображения в буфер обмена

Tags: java, изображения

Добрый день) Помогите загрузить изображение:

```
package Laba;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

public class LoadImage {
    public static BufferedImage image(String path) throws Exception{
        return ImageIO.read(new File(path));
    }
}

package Laba;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        LoadImage.image("1.jpg");
    }
}
```

Код ошибки:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read
>   input file!   at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)    at
>   Laba.LoadImage.image(LoadImage.java:16)   at
>   Laba.Test.main(Test.java:11)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно уточнить путь - вместо `"1.jpg"` указать полный путь к файлу, например, `"c:\folder\1.jpg"`

Вы также можете положить изображение в папку resources вашего проекта, и тогда метод image изменить следующим образом:

```
 public static BufferedImage image(String path) throws Exception{

        return ImageIO.read(new File(getClass().getResource("/resources/" + path).toURI()));
    }
```